# Confusion related to Python's `in` operator

Tags: python

I found strange behavior with Python's `in` operator

```
d = {}
'k' in d == False # False!
```

I thought it's because of precedence:

```
('k' in d) == False # True, it's okay
'k' in (d == False) # Error, it's also okay
```

But, what precedence evaluates the following expression then?

```
d = {}
'k' in d == False
```

If it's because of wrong precedence why it doesn't fire an error like if:

```
'k' in (d == False)
```

In other words, what happens under the hood of Python with this expression?

```
'k' in d == False
```

Comment: `'k' in [d == False]` will evaluate to `False`

Comment: I'll remember to ask this again some day. Astounding that this still collects so many upvotes, unlike other unresearched duplicate questions which just gather downvotes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`in` is considered a comparison operator, and so it is subject to comparison chaining.

```
'k' in d == False
```

is equivalent to

```
'k' in d and d == False
```

because both `in` and `==` are comparison operators.

You virtually *never* need direct comparison to Boolean literals, though. The "correct" expression here is `'k' not in d`.

---

For reference, this is described in the Python documentation, under [6.10. Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> ```
> comparison    ::=  or_expr (comp_operator or_expr)*
> comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
>                    | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
> ```

and

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).